# Only on iPhone 5s and previous: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [50 nan]'

Tags: ios, iphone, calayer

The crash occurs on iPhone 5s (real device, in the simulator the app does not crash) and previous models.

The code crashes here.

```
private lazy var progressViewMaskLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let progressViewMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    progressViewMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.bounds.width - 8, height: self.bounds.width - 8)).CGPath
    return progressViewMaskLayer
}()

private func setProgressViewHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    let size = progressViewMaskLayer.frame.size
    let origin = progressViewMaskLayer.frame.origin
    progressViewMaskLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: height) // CRASH HERE!
    progressViewMaskLayer.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: origin.x, y: 64.0 - height)
}

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [0 nan]'
```

Comment: try this progressViewMaskLayer.frame.size = CGSize(width: isnan(size.width)?1:size.width, height: isnan(height)?1:height)

Comment: Thanks @Hector! Didn't know about the insan() function.

Comment: its isnan() not insan().

Comment: It was just a typo